# SQLite Howto delete entries from sqlite_sequence?

Tags: android, sqlite, sequence, greendao

i use GreenDao and create entries for a Category, which perfectly works. My problem is, when i repeat the action, it comes a failure with **de.greenrobot.dao.DaoException: Entity is detached from DAO context**.
I looked in the database with SQLite Debugger and saw **every time** i insert these entries an entry in sqlite_sequence appeared. I deleted it manually with my app "SQLite Debugger".
After this it works.

Now the question. How can i do this automatically?

**CodeSnippet**

```
if (category_CategoriesCompaniesQuery == null || category_CategoriesCompaniesQuery.equals(null)) {
        QueryBuilder<CategoryCompany> tempQueryBuilder = queryBuilder();
        tempQueryBuilder.where(Properties.CategoryID.eq(categoryID));
        category_CategoriesCompaniesQuery = tempQueryBuilder.build().forCurrentThread();
    } else {
        category_CategoriesCompaniesQuery.forCurrentThread().setParameter(0, categoryID);
    }
    return category_CategoriesCompaniesQuery.forCurrentThread().list();
}
```

**Stacktrace**

> 02-04 12:05:38.883: E/AndroidRuntime(23568): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>   02-04 12:05:38.883: E/AndroidRuntime(23568):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
>   02-04 12:05:38.883: E/AndroidRuntime(23568):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>   02-04 12:05:38.883: E/AndroidRuntime(23568):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>   02-04 12:05:38.883: E/AndroidRuntime(23568):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>   02-04 12:05:38.883: E/AndroidRuntime(23568):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>   02-04 12:05:38.883: E/AndroidRuntime(23568):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   02-04 12:05:38.883: E/AndroidRuntime(23568):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   02-04 12:05:38.883: E/AndroidRuntime(23568):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
>   02-04 12:05:38.883: E/AndroidRuntime(23568): Caused by: de.greenrobot.dao.DaoException: Entity is detached from DAO context
>   02-04 12:05:38.883: E/AndroidRuntime(23568):    at com.adamasvision.mytermin.model.Category.getCategoriesCompanies(Category.java:152)
>   02-04 12:05:38.883: E/AndroidRuntime(23568):    at com.adamasvision.mytermin.UserState$1.doInBackground(UserState.java:415)
>   02-04 12:05:38.883: E/AndroidRuntime(23568):    at com.adamasvision.mytermin.UserState$1.doInBackground(UserState.java:1)
>   02-04 12:05:38.883: E/AndroidRuntime(23568):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>   02-04 12:05:38.883: E/AndroidRuntime(23568):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)

Comment: Please add your code and stacktrace.

Comment: added code and stacktrace

Comment: You're trying to solve the wrong problem. `sqlite_sequence` is not the problem. You should fix the "Entity is detached from DAO context" instead. There are plenty of results on SO for that.

Comment: Please post the complete code of `getCategoriesCompanies`.

Answer (score 0):

`sqlite_sequence` keeps track of autoincrement values. You should not mess with it, because it will probably destroy your dataintegrity.

Comment: Yeah i know it down't help to delete it automatically because the seperate app closes the background tasks of my app and by my automatic deleting i don't want to do this.
I searched a bit [and found here a possible answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611564/greendao-entity-is-detached-from-dao-context). I have to use "loadDeep" and "queryDeep", but i don't know how to use it. Do you know it or can you help me?